# Microsoft Excel Macro Coding Issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Macro however it doesnt seem to be working. I have a workbook which has multipul worksheets. I basically want to copy cells B1, G1, M94 all to a seperate "Summary" worksheet. Copied Cells to go to A4 B4 and C4 than if there is more A5, B5 and C5 and so on.

The coding i have is below. I have tried to make it so it only did it for one sheet but need it for about 10 sheets all with different names.

```
Sub SummurizeSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Summary").Activate

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "17B CUNNINGHAM" Then
        ws.Range("B1, G1, M94").Copy
        Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) _
            .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you will have is you cannot copy/ paste a range the way you have tried to (multiple sections).This should work:

```
Sub SummurizeSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet, wsSummary As Worksheet
Dim c As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wsSummary = Sheets("Summary")
' Set destination cell
Set c = wsSummary.Range("A4")

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "17B CUNNINGHAM" And ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
        ws.Range("B1").Copy
        c.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        ws.Range("G1").Copy
        c.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        ws.Range("M94").Copy
        c.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        ' Move destination cell one row down
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    End If

Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have used a destination cell to place the paste which you can then offset for the next row so you can use this for multiple sheets. Also excluded the Summary sheet from the `For Each`  and reset the `ScreenUpdating`

Comment: This worked perfect. Your a champion Thank you so much